# background-size: cover; makes page scrollable to sides

Tags: html, css

I am testing out the parallax scrolling effect, in which there is a background picture and by scrolling, you can see different parts of the picture. The problem is, when I zoom out the page, the picture repeats, which is ugly. I have tried no-repeat; and it only makes the picture stay in one corner, and I have tried background-size: cover; which makes the page scrollable to sides which I don't need.

How to deal with this?

EDIT: I'm sorry for forgetting to post the code.

HTML & CSS:

```css
.parallax {
    background: url("http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/02/19/latest-space-wallpaper_110926700_30.jpg") center fixed;
}

.parallax-inner{
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
     <section class="parallax">
    
        <div class="parallax-inner">
      
              <h2>My First Heading</h2>
        </div>
    
    </section>
```

Example: http://prntscr.com/9jv8d4

Zoomed out: http://prntscr.com/9jv8sd

No-repeat; http://prntscr.com/9jv94p

Cover and on 1920x1080 screen, default 100% zoom; http://prntscr.com/9jv9ur (page is scrollable to the far right side)

Comment: You need to post your code

Comment: please post your sample code

Comment: what if you remove that css and put `background-color` instead?

Comment: Just tried, that works. Image size used for background was 1920x1080, is that too large or something?

Comment: Why can't you use background-size:cover? it works fine for me.

Comment: no if you put `background-size:cover` it will fit no matter how large or small the image is

Comment: it would be useful to know what browser(s) you tested in

Comment: I used Google Chrome for testing.

Comment: I would also suggest you use something like https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ and then test again.

Comment: maybe try `background-size: 100% 100%` instead of `cover`, if you **really**  need COVER then  set the `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Esteban rincon's solution worked like a charm. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: wouldn't it be stretched or be squished on height or width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your css code to be as following:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.parallax {
    background: url(latest-space-wallpaper_110926700_30.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax-inner{
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

i tested it on my own and works fine, hope this will help you.

resource will be useful for you:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

**just use**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```